# How to config esrally metric store so that meta part of rally-metrics-* can record took of each query

Tags: elasticsearch

I use metric store to save esrally results.
Some of my results, the "meta" includes "took" of each query:

```
"meta": {
           "plugins": [
             "vector"
           ],
           "attribute_xpack.installed": "true",
           "source_revision": "053779d",
           "distribution_version": "6.3.2",
           "distribution_flavor": "default",
           "index": "trademark_multi",
           "took": 129,
           "success": true,
           "success-count": 50,
           "error-count": 0
},
```

However, some result are not.
Which setting that I can configure for "took" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For search operations, setting detailed-results to true to return took time in meta-data.
https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/stable/track.html#id8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).